# Changing python3 file into executable from command line?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I know that in bash you can make a python2 file executable with `chmod +x file_name.py`.

I was wondering if u can do something similar to make python3 files executable in the same way?

Do I have to add another argument?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Kefeng91 yes, some exclusive python3 syntax causes errors as it is being run with python2.

Comment: @DukeVanDirt add `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of your file. The path to your python3 iterpreter. The script should run with python3. You can read more on wiki about [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))